# Background image doesn't show up in render

Tags: rendering

If I try to render a background image, the image doesn't show up. I use blender version 2.75a. I used the composite approach:

So, Render layer, image input, alphaOver and composite output, there are many tutorials showing this approach, but is doesn't work in my case.

Note that I see my background image and 3d object in camera persp.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show a picture of your node setup?

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply. I found the solution on this forum. For Blender Render I set the transparency in the shading panel. Now it's working. By the way, If using Cycles, you need to switch you film to transparent in the render setting panel